# Vuex - Get params on $store.state

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a `v-select` form that will generate data based on the first selected `v-select` form (dynamic drop-down list). I was able to achieve this in a single file component passing values using `params` without the use of Vuex.

Now I have translated my first `v-select` form to Vuex and I am confused on how will I pass the "id" to the second `v-select` form? Please refer to the code below.

**Component.vue (without Vuex)**

```html
    <v-select 
      v-model="rows.corporate_objective_id"
      :items="corporate_objectives" 
      item-text="corporate_objective" 
      item-value="id" 
      placeholder="Please select a Corporate Objective"
      dense
      clearable
      @change='getDepartmentObjectives()'
    ></v-select>

     getDepartmentObjectives() {
            axios
            .get('/api/department-objective-appraisal', {
              params: {
                corporate_objective_id: this.rows.corporate_objective_id
              }
            })
            .then(response => this.department_objectives = response.data)
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
          },
```

And here is the code below where I am now using Vuex.

**Component.vue (with Vuex)**

```js
    //Actions
    const corporateObjectives = ({ commit }) =>
      axios
      .get('/api/corporate-objective-select')
      .then(response => commit('SET_CORPORATE_OBJECTIVES', response.data))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))

    //Mutations
    const SET_CORPORATE_OBJECTIVES = (state, corporate_objectives) =>
      state.corporate_objectives = corporate_objectives
```

How do I achieve the same result from the first code to Vuex?

Also is it possible getting the v-model from the store with a syntax like this? `v-model:this.$store.state`?

Comment: Have a look at https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html

Comment: Thank you for the v-model answer.